# inline style for Div or span not making element inline

Tags: angular5

I have a `bootstrap3` `navbar`. The `navbar` has a login form on the right and  login and signup buttons. I want that once the user logs in successfully, these controls disapper and signup and profile links come up (and vice versa when the user clicks sign out). I am able to do this using `[hidden]="someValue"` but I suppose using `hidden` is not the right approach. I thought of doing it using `*ngIf` but my issue is that the login form and sign up buttons appear in separate lines and not in single line. I tried using `<div>` with `inline` style and also `<span>` but it didn't work

```
 <div *ngIf = "userNotloggedIn" [ngStyle]="{display: inline}"> <!--tried span as well but it didnt' work either-->
        <li ><!-- Navbar Form --> <!-- Instead of ngIf, if I use [hidden]="!userNotloggedIn" for each li then it works but I want to use ngIf-->
          <form class="form-inline" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="signInUser()" novalidate>
            <label for="username" class="control-label required sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" formControlName="userName" [ngClass]="validateField('userName')" required>
            <app-show-errors [control]="loginForm.controls.userName"></app-show-errors>
            <label for="password" class="control-label required sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" formControlName="password" [ngClass]="validateField('password')" required>
            <app-show-errors [control]="loginForm.controls.password"></app-show-errors>

              <button type="submit" id="login-button" class="btn content-div__button--blue btn-sm">Sign In</button>

          </form>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" > <!-- [hidden]="!userNotloggedIn" works-->
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="signupRouterLink">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!userNotloggedIn" [ngStyle]="{display: inline}">

        <li class="nav-item" > <!-- [hidden]="userNotloggedIn" works-->

          <a [routerLink]="" (click)="onProfileClick()">My Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" > <!-- [hidden]="userNotloggedIn" works -->
          <a [routerLink]="" (click)="onSignoutClick()">Sign out</a>
        </li>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem using `ng-container` instead of `div` or `span` but I don't know why `div` or `span` didnt work. Happy to accept answers which can explain this.